# How to swap HTMLTableCellElement nodes in a table

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table, deep-copy

I have a HTML table like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/link_a.html">col A</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/link_b.html"><span class="special">col B</span></a>
            </td>
            <td>other cols
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value A
            </td>
            <td>value B
            </td>
            <td><span class="morespecial">more values</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this table I want to copy via JavaScript some cells from one column to another (later I want to *swap* them, but to make it easier here I just want to overwrite some cells from others).

So I have written something like this:

```
    var tableObj = document.getElementById("mytable")
    for (var r of tableObj.rows) {
        var cell_store = {};
        for (var [i, c] of enumerate (r.cells)) {
            cell_store [i] = c;
        }
        r.cells [0] = cell_store [1];
    }
```

Basically I get the table object, iterate over the rows and over the columns getting `HTMLTableCellElement` nodes. I store some of these in a dictionary and then assign stored nodes to different cells in the table, but instead of a modified table I get an in-browser error "*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 0 is read-only*".

What do I do wrong here? How can I copy `HTMLTableCellElement` nodes (with all its sub-objects like links and spans) from one node to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manipulate DOM you should use DOM objects' methods.
For you particular case use [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). When you add a node to some other element it's removed from the previous one.

Also you can use `element.innerHTML` to swap rather HTML than nodes. In some cases working with pure HTML is faster than working with nodes. Benchmark your particular cases.

For your particular case just swap the cells with [Node.insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) or something like that. Just learn DOM manipulation methods.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with `element.innerHTML`. This makes it a lot easier than moving the complete nodes around.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you can accomplish what you want using.
[replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith)
So in your example `r.cells [0].replaceWith(cell_store [1]);`

You can also safely use [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove), as long as you have a reference to the element you can always add it back using:

- [replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith)
- [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)
- [after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after)

And more, have a look at [MDN - Element docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) for all methods.